# How can I replace an element of a list using an index in PROLOG

Tags: list, prolog

I need do this:

`replace(L,P,E,R)`, where L is the current list, P is the position where the element will be insert, E is the element to insert and R is the return, the new list.

Example:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5],
replace(L,2,'@',R).
R = [1,2,'@',4,5]
```

I tried this, but nothing happens, the list continuous to be the same:

```
replaceInThePosition([_|T],1,E,[['1',E]|T]).
replaceInThePosition([H|T],P,E,[H|R]) :-
    P > 0, NP is P-1, replaceInThePosition(T,NP,E,R), !.
```

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, SWI-Prolog's [`select/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=select/4) might be useful for your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not far.

You can try with

```
replaceInThePosition([_|T],0,E,[E|T]).
replaceInThePosition([H|T],P,E,[H|R]) :-
    P > 0, NP is P-1, replaceInThePosition(T,NP,E,R).
```

I mean:

1) `0` instead `1` in the first clause (or `1` in the first clause but `P > 1` in the second one; but in this case from `replaceInThePosition([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2, '@', R)` you unify `R = [1, @, 3, 4, 5]`, not `R = [1, 2, @, 4, 5]`)

2) `[E|T]` for the last ergument in the first clause, not `[['1',E]|T]`

3) no cut (no `!`) at the end of the second clause (there is no need: the first clause i when `P` is zero; the secon one when `P > 0`; so they are mutually exclusive

Answer (score 1):

another possibility:

```
/*
L is the current list,
P is the position where the element will be insert,
E is the element to insert and
R is the return, the new list
*/
replaceInThePosition(L, P, E, R) :-
    findall(X, (nth0(I,L,Y), (I == P -> X=E ; X=Y)), R).
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using `append/3`:

```
substitute(L, P, E, R) :-
    PreLen is P - 1,
    length(PreLen, P1),
    append(Pre, [_|T], L),
    append(Pre, [E|T], R).
```