# How can I verify if a coordinate is in a list

Tags: prolog

I'm generating random coordinates and adding on my list, but first I need verify if that coordinate already exists. I'm trying to use `member` but when I was debugging I saw that isn't working:

My code is basically this:

```
% L is a list and Q is a count that define the number of coordinate
% X and Y are the coordinate members
% check if the coordniate already exists
% if exists, R is 0 and if not, R is 1
createCoordinates(L,Q) :-
    random(1,10,X),
    random(1,10,Y),
    convertNumber(X,Z),
    checkCoordinate([Z,Y],L,R),
    (R is 0 -> print('member'), createCoordinates(L,Q); print('not member'),createCoordinates(L,Q-1).

checkCoordinate(C,L,R) :-
    (member(C,L) -> R is 0; R is 1).

% transforms the number N in a letter L
convertNumber(N,L) :-
    N is 1, L = 'A';
    N is 2, L = 'B';
    ...
    N is 10, L = 'J'.

%call createCoordinates
createCoordinates(L,20).
```

When I was debugging this was the output:

[image: debugging]

In this picture I'm in the firts interation and L is empty, so R should be 1 but always is 0, the coordinate always is part of the list.
I have the impression that the `member` clause is adding the coordinate at my list and does'nt make sense

Comment: Can you show what query you entered, expected result of that query, and what result you actually got instead? Your trace just shows you're checking your list for an element that looks like `[X, 4]` (`X` is an uninstantiated variable). Your code also isn't designed well for Prolog. You're trying to use it imperatively, like C, rather than declaratively. `convertNumber` should not be a predicate, but a set of facts: `number_map(1, 'A'). number_map(2, 'B').` etc, Or, you could calculate one argument from the other using Prolog's atom and character handling predicates (see the documentation).

Comment: Thank you for answer! I edited the question and did the change that you suggested, I'm new in prolog and is very hard think in the imperatively way

Comment: I don't see any changes to the question. Also, see my second comment above about `member` failure. A Prolog predicate succeeds or fails. It fails if it cannot make the expression succeed when executed. Thus, `member(X, [])` always fails since `[]` has no members.

Comment: Previous questions by OP. [How can I replace a list in Prolog?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41468676/1243762) and [How can I replace an element of a list using an index in PROLOG](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41454755/1243762)

Comment: I see you edited the question with a new trace, but I still do not see what query you entered. Also the code you show in your problem is incomplete (the first set of code is part of the tail end of a predicate clause and is missing the head and, perhaps, some initial code). It doesn't, for example, show how `L` is handled before the `checkCoordinate/3` call.

Comment: If you have not done this please do so. Take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also in particular read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and adjust your question accordingly. I tried your example code and it does not even compile. In other words if you do make it easy for others to help you then they will not help you.

Comment: Helpful hint. You should not have `...` in your sample code. Think about what the person who is trying to help you is doing. They copy your code to make sure it compiles first, however `...` does not compile so they have to enter it themselves. Then if you make an edit to the code they have to do it all over again. If  you were taking a class and turned in code like that what grade would you get? As I noted, make it easy for those helping you

Comment: What's the purpose of `C is Q`? I suspect you are getting a singleton variable warning for `C` since it isn't used anywhere else in the clause.

Comment: Note that `createCoordinates(L,Q-1)` will not do what you think. `Q-1` is just a Prolog term that is syntactic sugar for `'-'(Q,1)`. Prolog will not evaluate it inline. If you want it evaluated, you need to use an evaluating operator, such as `is/2`: `Q1 is Q - 1, createCoordinates(L, Q1)`.

Comment: @GuyCoder I'm sorry, I thinked that the rest of my code didn't matter, and I saw that this was my mistake. I'm not declaring L, and thought that this do'nt make difference but when I read the lurker comment I decided make a test doing L = [] and it worked. Thank you so much! 
I just had a question: if I do not do L = [], how does prolog interpret? I always thought this was not necessary

Comment: If `L` is a variable, uninstantiated, then `member(X, L)` will *always succeed*. Are you trying to create a list? It's a little unclear. Nowhere in your code do you actually instantiate the list argument. So it's always a variable and the `member(X, L)` always succeeds.

Comment: @lurker I just realized now that C is Q is no longer necessary. I used this in a previous test and forgot to delete it. My mistake is don't do L = [], I always thought this was not necessary. Sorry for the confusion, I did not put the rest of the code just because I thought it was not relevant, since in my head L just appears and did his part.

Comment: I went down the wrong analysis path with `L = []`. See my last comment about `member(X, L)` with `L` uninstantiated.

Comment: @GuyCoder I don't see any harm in ellipsis here, it's totally obvious what is meant. I think your standards for question-asking are a little too stringent.

Comment: @GuyCoder This is the third or fourth question I have had no trouble answering as asked, where you have quibbled the asker about their question's formatting or sent them to the question guidelines. I think your suggestions display great empthy for the answerer but you should shift some of that empathy onto the user. They're here for help. Demanding minutia from them is setting the wrong tone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I would recommend breaking your problem down into smaller pieces. You should have a procedure for making a random coordinate:

```
random_coordinate([X,Y]) :- 
    random(1, 10, XN), convertNumber(XN, X), 
    random(1, 10, Y).
```

Second, your `checkCoordinate/3` is converting Prolog's success/failure into an integer, which is just busy work for Prolog and not really improving life for you. `memberchk/2` is completely sufficient to your task (`member/2` would work too but is more powerful than necessary). The real problem here is not that `member/2` didn't work, it's that you are trying to build up this list parameter on the way out, but you need it to exist on the way in to examine it.

We usually solve this kind of problem in Prolog by adding a third parameter and prepending values to the list on the way through. The base case then equates that list with the outbound list and we protect the whole thing with a lower-arity procedure. In other words, we do this:

```
random_coordinates(N, Coordinates) :- random_coordinates(N, [], Coordinates).

random_coordinates(0, Result, Result).
random_coordinates(N, CoordinatesSoFar, FinalResult) :- ...
```

Now that we have two things, `memberchk/2` should work the way we need it to:

```
random_coordinates(N, CoordinatesSoFar, FinalResult) :- 
   N > 0, succ(N0, N),   % count down, will need for recursive call
   random_coordinate(Coord),
   (memberchk(Coord, CoordinatesSoFar) -> 
       random_coordinates(N, CoordinatesSoFar, FinalResult)
   ;
       random_coordinates(N0, [Coord|CoordinatesSoFar], FinalResult)
   ).
```

And this seems to do what we want:

```
?- random_coordinates(10, L), write(L), nl.
[[G,7],[G,3],[H,9],[H,8],[A,4],[G,1],[I,9],[H,6],[E,5],[G,8]]

?- random_coordinates(10, L), write(L), nl.
[[F,1],[I,8],[H,4],[I,1],[D,3],[I,6],[E,9],[D,1],[C,5],[F,8]]
```

Finally, I note you continue to use this syntax: `N is 1, ...`. I caution you that this looks like an error to me because there is no distinction between this and `N = 1`, and your predicate could be stated somewhat tiresomely just with this:

```
convertNumber(1, 'A').
convertNumber(2, 'B').
...
```

My inclination would be to do it computationally with `char_code/2` but this construction is actually probably better.

Another hint that you are doing something wrong is that the parameter `L` to `createCoordinates/2` gets passed along in all cases and is not examined in any of them. In Prolog, we often have variables that appear to just be passed around meaninglessly, but they usually change positions or are used multiple times, as in `random_coordinates(0, Result, Result)`; while nothing appears to be happening there, what's actually happening is plumbing: the built-up parameter becomes the result value. Nothing interesting is happening to the variable directly there, but it is being plumbed around. But nothing is happening at all to L in your code, except it is supposedly being checked for a new coordinate. But you're never actually appending anything to it, so there's no reason to expect that anything would wind up in L.

**Edit** Notice that @lambda.xy.x solves the problem in their answer by prepending the new coordinate in the head of the clause and examining the list only after the recursive call in the body, obviating the need for the second list parameter.

**Edit 2** Also take a look at @lambda.xy.x's other solution as it has better time complexity as N approaches 100.

Comment: Thank you!!!! Are you a genius hahaha prolog is so hard and you help me a lot with your explanation, you really clarified so many things that I did not even know I had doubts about it.

Comment: @Marcio we've all been where you are now! It takes some getting used to but you will come to understand Prolog if you give it time and keep hacking at it!

Answer (score 2):

Since i had already written it, here is an alternative solution: The building block is `gen_coord_notin/2` which guarantees a fresh solution `C` with regard to an exclusion list `Excl`.

```
gen_coord_notin(C, Excl) :-
    random(1,10,X),
    random(1,10,Y),
    ( memberchk(X-Y, Excl) ->
      gen_coord_notin(C, Excl)
    ;
      C = X-Y
    ).
```

The trick is that we only unify `C` with the new result, if it is fresh.
Then we only have to fold the generations into `N` iterations:

```
gen_coords([], 0).
gen_coords([X|Xs], N) :-
    N > 0,
    M is N - 1,
    gen_coords(Xs, M),
    gen_coord_notin(X, Xs).
```

*Remark 1*: since coordinates are always 2-tuples, a list representation invites unwanted errors (e.g. writing [X|Y] instead of [X,Y]). Traditionally, an infix operator like `-` is used to seperate tuples, but it's not any different than using `coord(X,Y)`.

*Remark 2*: this predicate is inherently non-logical (i.e. calling `gen_coords(X, 20)` twice will result in different substitutions for `X`). You might use the meta-level predicates `var/1`, `nonvar/1`, `ground/1`, `integer`, etc. to guard against non-sensical calls like `gen_coord(1-2, [1-1])`.

*Remark 3*: it is also important that the conditional does not have multiple solutions (compare member(X,[A,B]) and memberchk(X,[A,B])). In general, this can be achieved by calling `once/1` but there is a specialized predicate `memberchk/2` which I used here.

Answer (score 2):

I just realized that the performance of my other solutions is very bad for N close to 100. The reason is that with diminishing possible coordinates, the generate and test approach will take longer and longer. There's an alternative solution which generates all coordinates and picks N random ones:

```
all_pairs(Ls) :-
    findall(X-Y, (between(1,10,X), between(1,10,Y)), Ls).

remove_index(X,[X|Xs],Xs,0).
remove_index(I,[X|Xs],[X|Rest],N) :-
    N > 0,
    M is N - 1,
    remove_index(I,Xs,Rest,M).

n_from_pool(_Pool, [], 0).
n_from_pool(Pool, [C|Cs], N) :-
    N > 0,
    M is N - 1,
    length(Pool, L),
    random(0,L,R),
    remove_index(C,Pool,NPool,R),
    n_from_pool(NPool, Cs, M).

gen_coords2(Xs, N) :-
    all_pairs(Pool),
    n_from_pool(Pool, Xs, N).
```

Now the query

```
?- gen_coords2(Xs, 100).
Xs = [4-6, 5-6, 5-8, 9-6, 3-1, 1-3, 9-4, 6-1, ... - ...|...] ;
false.
```

succeeds as expected. The error message

?- gen_coords2(Xs, 101).
ERROR: random/1: Domain error: `not_less_than_one' expected, found`0'

when we try to generate more distinct elements than possible is not nice, but better than non-termination.

Comment: s(X), very nice! If we are in SWI and not limited to ISO, I would consider using `random_permutation/2` to shuffle the pool itself, and then just use `length/2` + `append/3` to select the first N of them. Of course you still get a domain error if the user does something silly.