# List is empty out of the clause, isn't being modified - PROLOG

Tags: prolog

I'm trying create a list of coordinate doing this:

```
insert(X,L,[X|L]). 

% L is a list and Q is a count that define the number of coordinate
% X and Y are the coordinate members
% check if the coordinate already exists
% if exists, R is 0 and if not, R is 1
% if the count is different of 0, I continous generating coordinates, else, I stop

createCoordinates(L,Q) :-
    C is Q,
    random(1,10,X),
    random(1,10,Y),
    convertNumber(X,Z),
    checkCoordinate([Z,Y],L,R),
    (C \== 0 -> (R is 0 -> createCoordinates(L,Q); insert([X,Y],L,A), createCoordinates(A,Q-1)); trace, print(L),print('Done!')).

checkCoordinate(C,L,R) :-
    (member(C,L) -> R is 0; R is 1).

convertNumber(1,'A').
convertNumber(2,'B').
convertNumber(3,'C').
convertNumber(4,'D').
convertNumber(5,'E').
convertNumber(6,'F').
convertNumber(7,'G').
convertNumber(8,'H').
convertNumber(9,'I').
convertNumber(1,'J').

% call createCoordinates
begin :-
    L = [],
    createCoordinates(L,20),
    print(L).
```

When I print the list inside the clause, all elements are there but when I print out of the clause, the list is empty.

When I was debugging it was like this:

[image: debug]

Probably it's a stupid error but I'm new in prolog and this really makes no sense to me.

Comment: Hint for the future: pleasy *copy* your stacktrace, do not *take a screenshot*.

Comment: Ok, sorry about this

Comment: Looks like you only partially followed the advice given by @DanielLyons and others in to your [other related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697608/how-can-i-verify-if-a-coordinate-is-in-a-list). You don't have proper termination of your predicate and it just unwinds, through backtracking, back to your initial empty list. It all stems to your attempting to handle the problem imperatively, which can eventually be forced to work, but will be more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

One fundamental aspect you need to understand about declarative languages like [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog) and [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell) is that they are - well - *declarative*: once you *define* a variable, you can *no longer alter its value*.

In other words writing `I = 1`, followed by `I = 4` will cause the program to fail.

In your "main" you write:

```
begin :-
    L = [],
    createCoordinates(L,20),
    print(L).
```

Here you see you have *fully instantiated* `L`, so it means that from now on, `L` will always be `[]`.

Therefore the problem is usually solved by defining predicate like:

```
predicate(Some,Parameters,Prior,Post)
```

where `Post` is a value *after* some effect is done on `Prior` (note that this does not mean you can only calculate `Post` out of `Prior`: most predicates in Prolog allow you to go the other direction as well).

So for your case, you would have to rewrite the `createCoordinates/2` to `createCoordinates/3`:

```
createCoordinates(Lin,Q,Lout)
```

Now you of course need to define this predicate. You can do this by altering it like:

```
createCoordinates(Lin,Q,Lout) :-
    C is Q,
    random(1,10,X),
    random(1,10,Y),
    convertNumber(X,Z),
    checkCoordinate([Z,Y],Lin,R),
    (C \== 0
     -> (R is 0
        -> createCoordinates(Lin,Q,Lout)
        ;  (insert([X,Y],Lin,A),
           createCoordinates(A,Q-1,Lout))
        )
    ; (trace,
       print(Lin),
       print('Done!'),
       Lout = Lin)
    ).
```

I took the liberty to reformat your code. As you can see, the predicate as well as the calls now use a `Lout` parameter. In the end, if we are `'Done!'`, we set `Lout = Lin`, this means that now `Lout` takes the value of the `Lin` with which we called the predicate.

You call it with:

```
begin :-
    Lin = [],
    createCoordinates(Lin,20,Lout),
    print(Lout).
```

Eliminating the `trace/0` and the inner `print/1` statements produces:

```
?- begin.
[[9,7],[7,1],[3,4],[7,7],[1,3],[9,1],[1,9],[8,8],[5,3],[8,3],[8,1],[6,3],[2,9],[3,6],[8,9],[6,6],[8,4],[6,3],[7,9],[4,1]]
```

This being said, your program is clearly written with an *imperative* mindset: this is not how a program in [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog) is supposed to look. The way `createCoordinates/3` is written can definitely be improved.

A better version would be:

```
createCoordinates(Lin,Q,Lin) :-
    Q < 0.

createCoordinates(Lin,Q,Lout) :-
    Q1 is Q-1,
    random(1,10,X),
    random(1,10,Y),
    convertNumber(X,Z),
    checkCoordinate([Z,Y],Lin,1),
    insert([X,Y],Lin,A),
    createCoordinates(A,Q1,Lout).
```

Nevertheless, even with these improvements, you still need a lot of refactoring.